# Django Form field created in __init__ does not exist in request.POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms, request

Form.py

```
class FormA(forms.ModelForm):
   fieldA = forms.CharField(required=True)
   fieldB = forms.CharField(required=True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   super(OfflineAccountEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   self.fields['fieldC'] = forms.CharField(required=True)

class Meta:
model = Profile
fields = ('username','first_name','last_name')
```

As you can see, I try to initiate a new field named fieldC in init function. During request 'get' method, it display nicely on form.

However, when I submit form, i print out my form, the fieldC field is missing.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    if obj:
        form = FormA(instance=obj)
    else:
        form = FormA()
else:
    if obj:
        form = FormA(request.POST, instance=obj)
    else:
        form = FormA(request.POST)

    print form
```

When I run cleaned_data, it can't find the field.

```
fieldC = form.cleaned_data['fieldC']
```

Any solution? Please guide. Thanks in advance and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you did not indent your `__init__()` method? or `Meta class`.

Comment: No, the indent was right. It's because the FieldC input was display perfectly in the GET request.